# Limit range of input() function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.8

I've tried searching for possible ways to set limits for the input().
It takes only absolute numbers, and I'd like to add a range for example 0-100.
Could you do it from the input() function itself or a if would be required?
If out of range, I don't want any output, just a error.
Thanks in advance

```
price_flour_kilo = abs(float(input()))
kilos_flour = abs(float(input()))
kilos_sugar = abs(float(input()))
packs_eggs = abs(float(input()))
packs_yeast = abs(float(input()))
price_sugar_kilo = price_flour_kilo * 0.75
price_pack_eggs = price_flour_kilo * 1.1
price_yeast_pack = price_sugar_kilo * 0.2
total_flour = price_flour_kilo * kilos_flour
total_sugar = price_sugar_kilo * kilos_sugar
total_eggs = price_pack_eggs * packs_eggs
total_yeast = price_yeast_pack * packs_yeast
result = total_eggs + total_flour + total_sugar + total_yeast
print(round(result, 2))
```

Comment: Yes, appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can define your input values by yourself:

```
def get_input(message, desired_values):
    user_input = input(message)
    if int(user_input) in desired_values:
        return user_input
    else:
        return get_input("Wrong input, possible inputs: {}: ".format(str(desired_values)), desired_values)

inp = get_input("Please your number: ", range(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function only reads an input. Even when you get an error when you enter a non-integer value to `int(input())`, it's the `int()` function that gives you an error. So it can't be done through the `input()` function. Any input handling of the kind that you're talking about has to be done using if-else conditions or something of the sort. Check whether the input satisfies your conditions and throw an error, if not.